# how can I mention coordinates in MongoDB if the longitude and latitude are shown in North and East

Tags: mongodb

how can I mention coordinates in MongoDB if the longitude and latitude are shown in North and East since MongoDB has only two coordinates and earth has NSEW coordinates

Comment: This question isn't really about programming.  Latitude and longitude can reference any point on the Earth.  Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Latitude_and_longitude for more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.